# Zeeman effect in a magnetic field with multiple components

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory

For calculating weak-field Zeeman energy shifts, the literature tends to assume the perturbing magnetic field is in the Z-direction; they choose their alignment such that this is true.

But what happens if the atom is in a magnetic field that has two components (in orthogonal directions)? In that case you can't just choose a coordinate system where the B-field lies along only one spatial direction.

Specifically: if I have an atom in a field with some nonzero magnitudes of $B_z$ and $B_y$, and I send along a laser in the Z-direction, will I notice an absorption spectrum shifted by

$E = g_j \mu_B m_j B_z $

What is the effect, if any, of $B_y$?

Comment: Turn the coordinate system along the direction of the field.

Comment: @Pieter I already mentioned that in my post. You can't do that here. Where do you orient your coordinate system? The two components are orthogonal.

Comment: The magnetic field at a point has only one direction. Call it $z$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this turned out to be embarrassingly trivial, as I apparently forgot how vectors work. Thanks to @Pieter's comment:

> The magnetic field at a point has only one direction. Call it z.

Comment: I disagree with the "not an answer" flag. This is the answer to the question: the direction of the magnetic field defines the quantization axis in the atom's frame of reference.